# How to send content to the instagram profile of any user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I want to perform write operation on users instagram profile. Is it somehow possible? Using Instagram/facebook APIs or access token or so?

Answer (score -1):

The post API endpoint is private. They only allow a few select third parties post directly to Instagram, if at all these days.

The only thing you can do is open Instagram with the media already selected.

Take a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed)